# Xcode 6 Swift Errors

Tags: xcode, swift

I keep getting these error messages.
But can´t figure out why. Anyone that might know how I can correct this?
I´m new to Swift, so all the help I can get is really appreciated. Thanks

Here is a printScreen of what I keep getting

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gvc9d8k03v11w7/Screen%20Shot%202014-11-19%20at%2022.48.12.png?dl=0

```swift
import UIKit

class SignUpViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtConfirmPassword: UITextField!


    @IBAction func SignUpButton(sender: UIButton) {
    }

    @IBAction func gotoLogin(sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(True, completion: nil)

    }
```

Xcode yells at me for: ""Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'"

Comment: Screen shot is terrible in terms of search results.  This question is mostly useless.  Anyone else with the same problem wouldn't possible be able to find these answers in a search result because your question's plain-text doesn't include anything to indicate the problem at all.

Comment: Ok. I hear you. So How would you suggest I post the question?

Comment: Your edit is a big improvement. The screenshot is good to include, but the plain text is more important.

Answer (score 2):

It's `true`, `false` and `Bool`, not `TRUE`, `True`, `FALSE`, `False` and / or `BOOL`, regardless of what the autocomplete tells you ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks.But do you know why it´s yelling at me for: "Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: Does it still do that after you change the first errors?

Comment: Yes, I get the comment: Use of unresolved identifier "True" and if I insert the ';' correction is tells me: "Expected declaration"

Comment: I was missing a close } at the end :-) But it is still complaining about the: Use of unresolved identifier "True"

Comment: Ok, now it is solved! I typed: "true" instead of "True" and "TRUE" But, what is the difference between all of these options ("true", "True" and "TRUE"), and why does auto-complete say something ("TRUE") that is not applicable?

Comment: Yeah, I saw that now. Sorry about that. Tired :-)

Comment: Because the keyword in Swift is true and nothing else.